# Finding optimal parameter for each input combination in the objective function in an optimization

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, nested-loops

I am calibrating a model and for that I have to estimate a parameter for each input combination I give to the objective function. I have a bit more than 10k input combinations and I want to minimize the parameter for each combination. All other variables in the model are known. I achieved to estimate 1 minimal value for the whole set but that doesn't help me, and when I tried my approach for each combination I get the error: Error in mP[, logik] <- mPv[, logik, drop = FALSE] : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments.

My objective function looks like this

```
x_vol <- vector(mode = "double", length = 10776)

objective_function_vol <- function(x_vol){
  
  S <- calibration_set$index_level
  K <- calibration_set$strike
  tau <- calibration_set$tau
  r <- calibration_set$riskfree_rate
  q <- calibration_set$q
  
  
  model_prices_vol <- vector(mode = "double", length = 10776)
 
  
  for (i in 1:10776){
    model_prices_vol[i] <- hestonCallcf(S = S[i], K = K[i], t = tau[i],
                                        r = r[i], q = 0,
                                        v0 = x_vol[i],
                                        vbar = 0.1064688, rho = -0.9914710,
                                        a = 1.6240300, vvol = 0.98839192)
    print(i)
  }
  
  diff_sq <- (market_price - model_prices_vol)^2
  wdiff <- diff_sq/market_price
  error <- sum(wdiff)/10776
  return(error)

}
```

I am using NMOF::DEopt for the optimization. Is it maybe possible to write a second loop which stores the optimal values of x_vol because I think using the subscript i for the known inputted values as well as the unknown is somehow wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that some objective-function calls resulted in `NA`.
If you only wish to minimize a single parameter (i.e. a scalar), Differential Evolution is probably not the method you want. A grid search along one dimension, possibly with refinements, would likely work better.

Comment: `NMOF::gridSearch` unfortunately also produces NA's. I specified lower and upper limits of 0.01 and 1 but the problem persists

Comment: No, it does not: it is the objective function that returns NA, not `gridSearch`. Both `gridSearch` and `DEopt` are repeated calls of the objective function. So use `try`, or something like `if (!is.finite(error)) large.number else error`, which will effectively mark solutions that lead to NA as very bad. (`large.number` is a constant you choose.)

Comment: The optimisation somehow always returns whatever value I define `large.number` as, which means that all my values are `NA`. I substituted the last line in the objective function with what you suggested and I call the optimisation with  `apply`: `apply(calib_df[,c("S", "K", "tau", "r", "market_price")], 1, function(x_vol)  gridSearch(fun = objective_function_vol, npar = 1L, lower = lb_vol, upper = ub_vol))`